# How repair/recreate Eclipse workspace and/or Maven caches/repositories?

Tags: eclipse, maven, workspace, corruption

I was creating some Maven project under Eclipse with using `spring-osgi-bundle-archetype` and this causes some plugins etc to download, which have frozen. After I killed Eclipse, many things related to Maven started to cause errors (Unable to download source code, Unable to find artifacts etc, without any apparent reason).

Looks like something was damaged in Eclipse cache or something.

How to clean and rebuild ALL which is possible in the situation?

Deletion of `core.eclipse.m2e.*` folders from workspace's `.metadata` folder didn't help.

**IF RECREATING PROJECT**

[image]

**IN POM FILE EDITOR**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Try the following:

1. rm -rf ~/.m2/repository
2. restart Eclipse with the -clean option

Comment: I have maven repository in different folder. It contains just jars and poms and also a `.cache` subfolder.

Comment: yep.  Get rid of that and try again

Answer (score 2):

You can delete .project and .classpath and execute command below in console to recreate eclipse project:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

This will generate eclipse required files for you.
reference: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html

If you have some trouble with downloading the dependent libraries, try `mvn install` in console and see the error message.

Above is based on the assumption that you can run `mvn` in console.